# Enabling a completed Java app on the web

Tags: java

I am not a Java pro. I need to enable my completed java applications to ONLINE-Versions. Kindly give me the simplest way.

I have tried to go the JSP and Servlet way, but seems exceedingly tiresome,there surely ought to be a direct way.

Comment: Have you tried the `--magic --transform-to-webapp` options of javac (just kidding). No, there's no direct way. A webapp is very very different from a console or rich-client app. Start coding.

Comment: I think "Ajax-Swing" is the magic behind all these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a typical web application what do you think is happening? You're in a browser and it's displaying some pages. You click around and some server does some work, for example Amazon shows you a list of books you could buy, the server is passing data to the browser for it to display.

That's a big difference from your current Java Application where everything is happening in the same computer.

This split between the UI part of the application, in the Browser, and the server part that's doing the real business is one reason why Web programming is so different from simple Java programming.

Servlets and JSPs are the traditional Java way of doing things, but modern web apps make much greater use of JavaScript for all the UI and all the Java (or any other server technology) does is provide the data displayed by JavaScript.

Bottom line: Sorry, but there is a whole lot more to learn. My recommendation would be to grit your teeth and forget about what you've done so far and start studying JavaScript and HTML.